# Clojure: parse json and extract values

Tags: json, clojure

I'm making an API call and using Cheshire to parse the JSON:

```
(defn fetch_headlines [source]
  (let [articlesUrl (str "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=" 
                         source
                         "&apiKey=a688e6494c444902b1fc9cb93c61d6987")]
    (-> articlesUrl
        client/get
        generate-string 
        parse-string)))
```

The JSON payload:

> {"status" 200, "headers" {"access-control-allow-headers" "x-api-key,
>   authorization", "content-type" "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>   "access-control-allow-origin" "*", "content-length" "7434",
>   "connection" "close", "pragma" "no-cache", "expires" "-1",
>   "access-control-allow-methods" "GET", "date" "Thu, 28 Mar 2019
>   20:22:16 GMT", "x-cached-result" "false", "cache-control" "no-cache"},
>   "body"
>   "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"totalResults\":10,\"articles\":[{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":null,\"title\":\"Trump:
>   Mueller probe was 'attempted takeover' of government - CNN
>   Video\",\"description\":\"In a Fox News interview with Sean Hannity,
>   President Trump called special counsel Robert Mueller's probe an
>   \\"attempted takeover of our
>   government.\\"\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/videos/politics/2019/03/28/trump-mueller-probe-attempted-takeover-hannity-cpt-sot-vpx.cnn\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190324191527-06-trump-mueller-reaction-0324-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T20:09:04.1891948Z\",\"content\":\"Chat
>   with us in Facebook Messenger. Find out what's happening in the world
>   as it
>   unfolds.\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":null,\"title\":\"James
>   Clapper reacts to call he should be investigated - CNN
>   Video\",\"description\":\"Former Director of National Intelligence
>   James Clapper reacts to White House press secretary Sarah Sanders
>   saying he and other former intelligence officials should be
>   investigated after special counsel Robert Mueller did not establish
>   collusion between the
>   Tr…\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/videos/politics/2019/03/26/james-clapper-reponse-mueller-report-sarah-sanders-criticism-bts-ac360-vpx.cnn\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190325211210-james-clapper-ac360-03252019-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T20:08:43.1736236Z\",\"content\":\"Chat
>   with us in Facebook Messenger. Find out what's happening in the world
>   as it
>   unfolds.\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":\"Maegan
>   Vazquez, CNN\",\"title\":\"Trump set for first rally since Mueller
>   investigation ended\",\"description\":\"President Donald Trump, making
>   his first appearance before supporters since Robert Mueller ended his
>   investigation, is set to speak during a rally in Grand Rapids,
>   Michigan Thursday
>   night.\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/2019/03/28/politics/donald-trump-grand-rapids-rally/index.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190321115403-07-donald-trump-lead-image-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T19:49:26Z\",\"content\":\"Washington
>   (CNN)President Donald Trump, making his first appearance before
>   supporters since Robert Mueller ended his investigation, is set to
>   speak during a rally in Grand Rapids, Michigan Thursday
>   night.\r\nThe rally follows a chaotic week in Washington, preci…
>   [+2099
>   chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":\"Katelyn
>   Polantz, CNN\",\"title\":\"Judge orders Justice Dept. to turn over
>   Comey memos\",\"description\":\"A federal judge has ordered that the
>   James Comey memos are turned over, in a court case brought by CNN and
>   other media organizations for access to the documents memorializing
>   former FBI Director's interactions with President Donald
>   Trump.\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/2019/03/28/politics/james-comey-memo-lawsuit/index.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/181209143047-comey-1207-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T19:14:45Z\",\"content\":\"Washington
>   (CNN)A federal judge has ordered that the Justice Department and FBI
>   submit James Comey's memos in full to the court under seal, in a court
>   case brought by CNN and other media organizations for access to the
>   documents memorializing the former FBI d… [+1043
>   chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":\"Clare
>   Foran and Manu Raju, CNN\",\"title\":\"Pelosi calls AG's summary of
>   Mueller report 'arrogant'\",\"description\":\"House Speaker Nancy
>   Pelosi on Thursday criticized Attorney General William Barr's summary
>   of special counsel Robert Mueller's report, calling it
>   \\"condescending\\" and \\"arrogant\\" and saying \\"it wasn't
>   the right thing to
>   do.\\"\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/2019/03/28/politics/pelosi-mueller-report-congress-barr-summary/index.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190328130240-02-nancy-pelosi-03282019-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T18:48:25Z\",\"content\":null},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":\"Analysis
>   by Chris Cillizza, CNN Editor-at-large\",\"title\":\"The 43 most
>   outrageous lines from Donald Trump's phone interview with Sean
>   Hannity\",\"description\":\"There's no \\"reporter\\" that President
>   Donald Trump likes more than Fox News' Sean Hannity -- largely due to
>   Hannity's unwavering, puppy dog-like support for the President. Trump
>   likes to reward people who play nice with him, which brings us to the
>   45-minute
>   ph…\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/2019/03/28/politics/sean-hannity-donald-trump-mueller/index.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190328140149-01-hannity-trump-file-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T18:44:21Z\",\"content\":\"(CNN)There's
>   no \\"reporter\\" that President Donald Trump likes more than Fox
>   News' Sean Hannity -- largely due to Hannity's unwavering, puppy
>   dog-like support for the President. Trump likes to reward people who
>   play nice with him, which brings us to the 45-minu… [+14785
>   chars]\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":null,\"title\":\"Puerto
>   Rico Gov.: I'll punch the bully in the mouth - CNN
>   Video\",\"description\":\"In an exclusive interview with CNN, Puerto
>   Rico Governor Ricardo Rosselló said he would not sit back and allow
>   his officials to be bullied by the White
>   House.\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/videos/politics/2019/03/28/ricardo-rossello-trump-bully-puerto-rico-sot-vpx.cnn\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190328123504-puerto-rico-gov-ricardo-rosello-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T18:08:33.7312458Z\",\"content\":\"Chat
>   with us in Facebook Messenger. Find out what's happening in the world
>   as it
>   unfolds.\"},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":\"Jeremy
>   Herb, Manu Raju and Ted Barrett, CNN\",\"title\":\"Jared Kushner
>   interviewed by Senate Intelligence
>   Committee\",\"description\":\"President Donald Trump's son-in-law
>   Jared Kushner returned to the Senate Intelligence Committee for a
>   closed door interview Thursday as part of the committee's Russia
>   investigation.\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/2019/03/28/politics/jared-kushner-senate-intelligence/index.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180302124221-30-jared-kushner-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T16:21:29Z\",\"content\":null},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":\"Jeremy
>   Herb and Laura Jarrett, CNN\",\"title\":\"Mueller report more than 300
>   pages, sources say\",\"description\":\"Special counsel Robert
>   Mueller's confidential report on the Russia investigation is more than
>   300 pages, according to a Justice Department official and a second
>   source with knowledge of the
>   matter.\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/2019/03/28/politics/mueller-report-pages/index.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/190324130054-05-russia-investigation-0324-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T15:52:01Z\",\"content\":null},{\"source\":{\"id\":\"cnn\",\"name\":\"CNN\"},\"author\":\"Jim
>   Acosta and Kevin Liptak, CNN\",\"title\":\"Exclusive: Puerto Rico
>   governor warns White House over funding\",\"description\":\"Tensions
>   are escalating between President Donald Trump and Puerto Rico's
>   governor over disaster relief efforts that have been slow in coming
>   for the still-battered island after Hurricane
>   Maria.\",\"url\":\"http://us.cnn.com/2019/03/28/politics/ricardo-rossell-donald-trump-puerto-rico-funding/index.html\",\"urlToImage\":\"https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180920230539-pr-storm-of-controversy-rossello-trump-super-tease.jpg\",\"publishedAt\":\"2019-03-28T15:19:39Z\",\"content\":null}]}",
>   "trace-redirects"
>   ["https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=a688e6494c444902b1fc9cb93c61d687"]}

I'd like to extract to extract the URLs from the returned JSON payload, I've tried this:

```
(defn fetch_headlines [source]
  (let [articlesUrl (str "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources="
                         source
                         "&apiKey=a688e6494c444902b1fc9cb93c61d697")]
    (-> articlesUrl
        client/get
        generate-string 
        parse-string
        (get-in ["source" "url"]))))
```

But I get a `nil` result, any ideas?

SOLUTION based on user feedback:

```
(defn fetch-headlines [source]
  (let [articlesUrl (str "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=" 
                         source
                         "&apiKey=a688e6494c444902b1fc9cb93c61d697")]
    (-> articlesUrl
        client/get
        :body
        parse-string
        (get-in ["articles" 0 "url"]))))
```

Comment: stop calling generate-string before parse-string? generate string just creates JSON from a clojure object, so you’re wrapping it and unwrapping it with the generate/parse pair.

Comment: best way of debugging this stuff is to build yhr expression up one clause at a time at the REPL, and male sure you understand the return value at each stage.

Comment: @pete23 calling "parse-string" directly on the JSON payload without "generate-string" returns an error:
classCastException clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String  cheshire.core/parse-string (core.clj:81)

Comment: look at what you have in your hand by executing this in the REPL. i suspect you’ll discover you now need to take the body as per the answer

Comment: parsed the body and got this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is inside the `body` key, but the value corresponding to that key is still a string and not yet a clojure map.  When you look for `source`, you're getting `nil` back because that key doesn't exist (it should be inside `body`, after correctly parsing the string into json).

Once you've properly parsed the `body` value, it should be something like:

```clj
(let [index-of-article 0]
  (get-in response ["body" "articles" index-of-article "url"]))
```

where `index-of-article` is the positional index of the article you want, since articles contains a vector of articles.

Comment: i tried this:

(defn fetch-headlines [source]
  (let [articlesUrl (str "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=" 
                         source
                         "&apiKey=a688e6494c444902b1fc9cb93c61d697")]
    (-> articlesUrl
        client/get
        generate-string 
        parse-string 
        (get "body")
        (get-in ["articles" [0] "url"])
        )))

Comment: @jwesonga it's just `0` - not `[0]`.  That was used to indicate a "placeholder".

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for fixing that - it was confusing in retrospect, but yes, I meant just to show that you need a positional index there.